# create table of contents using bookmarks in existing pdf

Tags: pdfbox

Is there any way create table of contents using bookmarks in existing pdf using pdfbox. I could able to read PDF bookmark and destination page numbers so now how could use the information to generate table of contents as like bookmark.

Comment: To add links, see the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download. Btw you don't use the page numbers, you use the PDPage objects. To position a text, see e.g. the HelloWorldTTF.java example. Your question is a bit broad IMHO, maybe reduce it to smaller problems.

Comment: I can add links but I want to add toc like tree structure as like bookmarks in PDF page. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What code did you create and what was the problem? You mentioned that you can access the bookmarks so you have the text and the destination page. Writing text on a page is explained in the Hello code, and you mentioned that you know how to set a link. Inserting a page before the beginning is done with `PDPageTree.insertBefore()`.